# Error while selecting dependent drop down and click the option In Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract links from all the combination of drop down elements. I have below code, but when I run the code it is throwing me error.

```
url = "https://www.ford.co.uk/owner/my-vehicle/download-your-manual"

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-year"))

data = []
for yearOption in selectYear.options:
    yearText = yearOption.text
    selectYear.select_by_visible_text(yearText)
    time.sleep(1)

    selectModel = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-model"))
    for modelOption in selectModel.options:
        modelText = modelOption.text
        selectModel.select_by_visible_text(modelText)
        data.append([yearText,modelText])


button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select this vehicle")
button.click()
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
content = soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"odl-download-link"})

links =[]
for i in content:
    links.append(i["href"])
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I change my question

Comment: When I add `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` then code works for me without errors.

Comment: to get pages for all combinations you would have to select first combination, click button, get links from new page, load again previous page using `driver.get(url)` and select second combinationa and click button, get links from second page and load again previous page, etc. Instead of loading again main page you could click link `<Back` on new pages.

Comment: links list given an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I had to add

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Second: I had to change indentations

Third: I had to add time.sleep(2) before getting page with links

And finally: I click `<Back` to go back

And it display links to manuals.

BTW: sometimes page shows popup window at start but I didn't try to solve this problem

BTW: I had to check

`if yearText != 'Year' and modelText != 'Model':`

to skip clicks for these values.

```
url = "https://www.ford.co.uk/owner/my-vehicle/download-your-manual"

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #'C:/Users/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-year"))

data = []
for yearOption in selectYear.options:
    yearText = yearOption.text
    selectYear.select_by_visible_text(yearText)
    time.sleep(1)

    selectModel = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-model"))
    for modelOption in selectModel.options:
        modelText = modelOption.text
        selectModel.select_by_visible_text(modelText)
        if yearText != 'Year' and modelText != 'Model':
            data.append([yearText, modelText])

            #print(data)

            button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select this vehicle")
            button.click()
            time.sleep(2)

            page = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            content = soup.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "odl-download-link"})

            links =[]
            for i in content:
                links.append(i["href"])

            print(links)

            # go back

            driver.find_element_by_class_name('odl-back-link').click()
```

Comment: This is the error "Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="odl-button odl-button-primary" data-ng-click="searchDownloadsWithSelect(selectedModel)" data-ng-disabled="!isModelSelected || selectedModel.id === 'default' || selectedYear.value === 'default' || isServiceError || noModelsAvailable" href="">...</a> is not clickable at point (588, 665). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.116)" running above code

Comment: sometimes page displays popup window and selections are hidden - code would need to check if there is popup window and click `close` on this window.